# Insert values from one table of objects to another table of objects

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have this datatype declared and afterwards populated:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE CRAMER."T_CREATELINK_PORTLIST" IS TABLE OF o_CreateLink_PORTLIST;
```

AND

```
TYPE o_CreateLink_PORTLIST AS OBJECT (
    PORTNAME                VARCHAR2(50),
    PORTID                  NUMBER,
    ISNEWPORT               NUMBER,
    SHELFNAME               VARCHAR2(50),
    SLOTNAME                VARCHAR2(50),
    BANDWIDTHNAME           VARCHAR2(50),
    ISSELECTED              NUMBER );
```

What I want to do is get some object/s from one table of this type to another table of same type. Something like this:

```
lsa_all_ports cramer.t_CreateLink_PORTLIST;
INSERT INTO lsa_filter_ports VALUES( SELECT *
      FROM TABLE(CAST(lsa_all_ports AS cramer.t_CreateLink_PORTLIST)) new
      WHERE new.bandwidthname = 'band2');
```

I'm pretty sure this syntax is wrong, but is there a simple way to do this??

Other atempts:

```
SELECT * INTO lsa_filter_ports
    FROM TABLE(CAST(lsa_all_ports AS cramer.t_CreateLink_PORTLIST)) new
    WHERE new.bandwidthname = 'band2';
```

> ORA-06550: not enough values

```
lsa_filter_ports cramer.t_CreateLink_PORTLIST := cramer.t_CreateLink_PORTLIST();    
INSERT INTO lsa_filter_ports 
     (SELECT * FROM TABLE(CAST(lsa_all_ports AS cramer.t_CreateLink_PORTLIST))
     WHERE bandwidthname = 'band2');
```

> ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood everything correctly You can do it like here:

```
declare 
  lsa_all_ports t_createlink_portlist := 
    t_createlink_portlist( o_createlink_portlist ('abc', 1, 'band1'), 
                           o_createlink_portlist ('def', 2, 'band2'));
  lsa_filter_ports t_createlink_portlist := t_createlink_portlist();
begin 
  select cast(multiset(select * 
                         from table(lsa_all_ports) 
                         where bandwidthname = 'band2') 
              as t_createlink_portlist)
    into lsa_filter_ports 
    from dual;
end;
```

Comment: Well besides that you understood what I need, you got the solution :) thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can better try to use the [SELECT...INTO command](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems045.htm) to do this.

> The SELECT INTO statement retrieves data from one or more database
>   tables, and assigns the selected values to variables or collections.

And if the table is already created and you want to insert into it then you can simply do like

```
insert into lsa_filter_ports 
select * from o_CreateLink_PORTLIST 
WHERE bandwidthname = 'band2'
```

Comment: I tried both of your proposed solutions but I'm not able to find the right syntax. I've updated the question

Answer (score 0):

Please see below the usage.

***--Created object***

```
 create or replace TYPE o_CreateLink_PORTLIST AS OBJECT (
        PORTNAME                VARCHAR2(50),
        PORTID                  NUMBER,
        ISNEWPORT               NUMBER,
        SHELFNAME               VARCHAR2(50),
        SLOTNAME                VARCHAR2(50),
        BANDWIDTHNAME           VARCHAR2(50),
        ISSELECTED              NUMBER );
```

***---created table same as object***

```
 create table lsa_filter_ports (
        PORTNAME                VARCHAR2(50),
        PORTID                  NUMBER,
        ISNEWPORT               NUMBER,
        SHELFNAME               VARCHAR2(50),
        SLOTNAME                VARCHAR2(50),
        BANDWIDTHNAME           VARCHAR2(50),
        ISSELECTED              NUMBER );
```

***--A type of object***

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE T_CREATELINK_PORTLIST IS TABLE OF o_CreateLink_PORTLIST;
```

***---Anonymous Block***

```
 declare
    lsa_all_ports  t_CreateLink_PORTLIST;

    begin

    INSERT INTO lsa_filter_ports 
          SELECT *
             FROM TABLE(CAST(lsa_all_ports AS t_CreateLink_PORTLIST)) new
                 WHERE new.bandwidthname = 'band2';


    end;
```

***Collection to collection copy***

```
declare
    lsa_all_ports     t_CreateLink_PORTLIST:= t_createlink_portlist(o_createlink_portlist ('abc', 1, 'band1'),o_createlink_portlist ('def', 2, 'band2'));
    lsa_filter_ports  t_CreateLink_PORTLIST:= t_createlink_portlist();

    cursor cur is 
              SELECT *
             --FROM TABLE(CAST(lsa_all_ports AS t_CreateLink_PORTLIST)) new
                 FROM TABLE(lsa_all_ports) new
                 WHERE new.bandwidthname = 'band2';

   begin

   for i in cur
     loop

         lsa_filter_ports.extend;

         lsa_filter_ports(cur%rowcount) := lsa_all_ports(cur%rowcount);

         dbms_output.put_line(lsa_filter_ports(cur%rowcount).PORTNAME);

     end loop;            


    end;
```

Comment: Can I do this insert for `lsa_filter_ports`  beeing of type `t_CreateLink_PORTLIST` ?? and not create a phisical table?

Comment: So you mean to say you wanted to have another object same as  t_CreateLink_PORTLIST  named lsa_filter_ports  and wanted all the values of the table to the new table..Am i correct, If yes then why do you want to store same result to 2 tables,

Comment: Yes I want to copy from one collection to another, but applying a filter `WHERE new.bandwidthname = 'band2';` this 'band2' will come as a parameter for a SP and then the `all_ports` and `filter_ports` collections will be sent as output

Comment: you can do it this way as well. Check my updated post,